# Cannot create a box in android

Tags: android

My customer requirement is to create a page which has three buttons and on click of that buttons it has to got to that specified urls of my website saying if we select login it has to got that particular page in my web application.I am very new to android and some how I have created that but he want that all to be in a box.I have searched in lots of sites saying custom dialog box,bla bla bla... but I didn't fine any solution. He has given me some website for reference and layout has to be like that.. that url is 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jwaala.mobile.redwoodcuorg&hl=en  in this url he want layout like first screen shot.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Button login;
    private Button register;
    private Button ContactUs;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
     register = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
     ContactUs= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

     login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("some url");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

        public void onClick1(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
     register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick2(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("some url");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

     ContactUs.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick1(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("some url");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}
```

layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:weightSum="6">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3.5" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/tasknbilllogo" />

    </RelativeLayout>

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:background="#ffff66"
           android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="30dp"


        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffa64c"
            android:text="-----"
             android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
            android:textColor="#4c4cff" />

          </RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="60dp"

         android:background="#ffa64c"
         android:textColor="#4c4cff"
            android:text="Register" />
    </RelativeLayout>
   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
          android:background="#ffa64c"
         android:textColor="#4c4cff"
        android:text="------" />
 </RelativeLayout>

   </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Here 's **all** you need to know about DialogBoxes: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: i have gone through it but in most of the custom layout links i saw they all will say to click on some "done" or some submit buttons and that opens list view. but for me it has to create a listview in dialog box and dialog box has to be in the second half of the page as first half of page is filled with logo..

Comment: i tried from 10days but no joy i have only 3days left to finsh....so i am in a bit hurry

Comment: Read the link I posted. Carefully. You don't need any more info.

Comment: `i tried from 10days` You should have found that link on the very first day. Then printed it, studied it, made it yours. And finally made your way through it. `9 days ago` at latest.

Comment: i am not an experienced developer....i am a manual tester who showed interest towards new works...some how i tried to write the code from browsing all around...i have gone through that link  but i thought like if a dialog box is only like a pop up....any way i have tried your code but it didn't worked.... i think i need to made some changes in your code..i will try

Comment: `I thought like if a dialog box is only like a pop up` Not really, since it can be complex to your liking. It's basically a window with a title and some Views and typically 1 or more buttons (typically "OK" or "Yes" and "No"). But it can also contain options. It can be customized to contain a different layout. I think it's really an easy beast to manage. You probably want simply 3 options (like 3 RadioButtons) in a Dialog. Or, as an alternative,  you could simply use a ListView, as suggested by @Strider. Or a RadioGroup with 3 RadioButtons inside.

Answer (score 0):

Use a listview:

**.XML**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
</ListView>
```

**Activity**

```
private ListView listView;
```

in your `onCreate()` method:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

the array:

```
// Defined Array values to show in ListView
String[] values = new String[] { "Login", 
                                 "Register",
                                 "Contact Us"};
```

new Adapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

Assign the adapter:

```
// Assign adapter to ListView
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and the `onItemClickListener()`:

```
// ListView Item Click Listener
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

    switch(position){
         case 1:
             Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://app.tasknbill.net/login.aspx");
             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
             startActivity(intent);
             break;

         case 2:  
            uri = Uri.parse("https://app.tasknbill.net/register.aspx");
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

         case 3:
            uri = Uri.parse("https://tasknbill.net/#contact");
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }

    }
});
```